# Measuring SMALL blobs in bitmap, using OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv, vision

I am in need to SIZE small white blobs on a black background, using OpenCV over C#.
Right now, I am starting to use the OpenCvSharp library, but, given that I am early in the development (started two days ago) I wonder if it's the best library for C#, or if you guys would use something else.

The task is to find small pinholes (In the 10/20 micron range, up to 100 micron) in an aluminum foil sample, which is placed in a machine that returns a 1800x1800 pixel picture with the pinholes on a black background.

My problem is simple, but the solution, I think, isn't: How do I "size" the pinhole, using OpenCV?

I know that the size is a clear indicator... But the smallest pinholes 10/15 micron are very difficult to recognize, because they are pretty similar in size (in the image), but vary in brightness.

Any of you guys find this challenge even remotely interesting?

Comment: Not sure this is a good fit for SO, but, if the position between the camera and the foil is fixed, then you could calculate how big each pixel is, and therefore once you find a block of x pixels, you know how big the hole is.  No need for OpenCV to do that.

Comment: Please note: asking for a tool recommendation is off-topic for SO because such recommendations are almost always opinion-based. Without having a *particular* programming problem, we are unable to answer your question. It looks like you're searching for a computer vision method in the first place. You should ask such questions on an appropriate site instead.

Comment: Yes, the position is absolutely fixed, in a dedicated dark room device, where le light of a flat panel lamp is shined on the bottom of a tin foil sample (10x10 cm).
I know I can measure the size of the (little) blobs, but the problem starts when they become too small, and similar, and the real difference is only the brightness.
I understand the point of view of dymanoid, though. Sorry for the question.